# Как добавить разметку через JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть div с содержимым:

```
<div class="item" id="iteminf">
    <span class="button_contents">Продать</span></a>
</div>
```

Как добавить к `div iteminf` ещё один `span`, при этом не заменяя всё что уже есть в `iteminf` ?

```
<span class="button_contents">Поменять</span></a>
```

Делаю так, но заменятся всё что есть в `iteminf`:

```
var but = '<span class="button_contents">Поменять</span></a>';
document.getElementById("iteminf").innerHTML = but;
```

Как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно - так:

```
myTargetElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
```

---

[MDN: Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

> Данная функция не переписывает имеющиеся элементы, что предовращает
>   дополнительную сериализацию и поэтому работает быстрее, чем
>   манипуляции с innerHTML.

Answer (score 3):

> Как добавить  к переменной `2`, при этом не заменяя ее значение
>   на `2`. Делаю:
>
> `x = 2;`
>
> но переменная становится равной `2`.

```
document.getElementById("iteminf").innerHTML += but;
```

P.S. У Вас там какой-то хвост `</a>` болтается.

Comment: `document.getElementById("iteminf").innerHTML += but;` покороче будет.

Comment: @Regent -Мы сэкономили цистерну чернил, не ставя точки над "ё". -А мы трудоустроили десять человек, расставляя эти точки.